# Summarize rows by other column values - Countif in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df with this dataset:

```
customer action    date
1049381  share    9/29/2017
1049381  level_up 10/6/2017
105460   share    9/22/2017
105460   share    9/23/2017
105668   level_up 9/8/2017
105668   share    9/8/2017
105668   level_up 9/18/2017
105668   share    9/18/2017
105668   share    9/20/2017
905669   share    9/25/2017
905669   level_up 9/25/2017
```

I want to count (summarize) those cases when the user made "level_up" and "share" on the same day(s). Like this:

```
customer  share_wth_level_up
1049381         0
105460          0
105668          2
905669          1
```

I have started with `pandas` but I cannot found the solution, because it doesn't provide a summarized df for every row (unique).

```
df.groupby(['customer','date']).size().value_counts()
```

result

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `GroupBy` + `nunique` and test for length equal to 2. Then use `GroupBy` + `sum` to total those instances.

```
df_grp = df.groupby(['customer', 'date'])['action'].nunique() == 2
res = df_grp.groupby('customer').sum().astype(int)

print(res)

customer
105460     0
105668     2
905669     1
1049381    0
Name: action, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `duplicated` filter the df firstly , then we groupby customer and date, to check all many `unique` value in action.

```
 s=df[df.groupby('customer').date.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,keep=False)].groupby(['customer','date']).action.nunique()
(s[s==2]//2).sum(level=0).reindex(df.customer.unique(),fill_value=0)
Out[166]: 
customer
1049381    0
105460     0
105668     2
905669     1
Name: action, dtype: int64
```